# Alternative for ActionBarDrawerToggle

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, actionbardrawertoggle

I'm creating an application which got both an `ActionBar` and a navigation drawer. I need a way to change the indicator of the action bar at some cases to have an up button (the arrow sign) instead of the 3 navigational drawer dots.

When trying to use `ActionBarDrawerToggle` I had many issues. I first used the v4 type which changed the appearence of the indicator but without changing the functionality (pressing the arrow button opened the drawer instead of going up the backstack). I tried using the v7 type but then this happened:

stackoverflow.com/questions/30591464/updating-v7-support-jar-causes-class-not-found-exception

So is there a way to acheive what I need via other ways?

Comment: Same problem is happening in my app right now.

Comment: Do you happen to know of a different way to change the action bar indicator to the arrow symbol without using the ActionBarDrawerToggle?

Comment: No. I had used v4 Library and ActionBar in older. after that when i updated  it to v7 it has removed logo from home button and put arrow key there.

Comment: When I use the v4 actionbardrawertoggle it did change the indicator to the symbol sign but just opened the drawer instead of going up...

Comment: you may need to check out that isDrawerOpen or not and according to it you need to close it or open it.

Comment: but even tough, it didn't go up the backstack.. when changing the indicator to the up arrow, doesn't it need to go up the backstack automatically?